# SQL Server Group By with Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

```
SELECT 
    [CustomerKey] AS 'Cust #',
    CU.[CompanyName] AS 'Company Name',
    ISS.InvoiceDate AS 'Invoice Date',
    ISS.InvoiceTotal AS 'Invoice Total',
    ISNULL(CU.ShopPhone,'') AS 'Company Shop',
    ISNULL(CU.CellPhone,'') AS 'Company Cell',
    ISNULL(CU.OfficePhone,'') AS 'Company Office',
    ISNULL(CF.FirstName, '') AS 'FName',
    ISNULL(CF.LastName,'') AS 'LName',
    ISNULL(CF.WorkPhone,'') AS 'Contact Work',
    ISNULL(CF.CellPhone,'') AS 'Contact Cell',
    ISNULL(CF.HomePhone,'') AS 'Contact Home',
    ISNULL(CF.EMail,'') AS 'Contact Email',
    PSO.OutsidePartsSalespersonName
FROM 
    [ProfitMaster].[dbo].[vwAC_SSR_Customer] CU with (nolock)
LEFT JOIN 
    [ProfitMaster].[dbo].[vwAC_SSR_InvoiceSalesSummary] ISS with (nolock) ON CU.CustomerKey = ISS.Customer
JOIN 
    [ProfitMaster].[dbo].[vwSV_INV_PartsSalesOrder] PSO with (nolock) ON PSO.PartsSalesOrderInvoiceID = ISS.PartsSalesOrderInvoiceID
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         EntityID, FirstName, LastName, WorkPhone, CellPhone, HomePhone, EMail 
     FROM 
         [ProfitMaster].[dbo].[vwGB_CON_ContactFull] with (nolock)  
     WHERE 
         EntityID IS NOT NULL 
         AND FirstName <> '' 
         AND EntityTypeID = '3' 
         AND SetDefault = '1'
     GROUP BY 
         EntityID, FirstName, LastName, WorkPhone, CellPhone, HomePhone, EMail) AS CF ON CU.CustomerID = CF.EntityID
WHERE 
    CU.Inactive = '0' 
    AND ISS.InvoiceType = 'Parts Order'
    AND ISS.InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2017-03-31 3:59:59.000'
    AND CU.CustomerBaseBranchID = '1'
    AND PSO.OutsidePartsSalespersonName IN ('Dave Freeland', 'Mark Miller', 'Ryan Oaks')
GROUP BY 
    CU.CustomerKey, CU.[CompanyName],
    ISS.InvoiceDate, ISS.InvoiceTotal, 
    CU.ShopPhone, CU.CellPhone, CU.OfficePhone, 
    CF.FirstName, CF.LastName, CF.WorkPhone, CF.CellPhone, 
    CF.HomePhone, CF.EMail, PSO.OutsidePartsSalespersonName
ORDER BY 
    CU.CompanyName, ISS.InvoiceDate
```

How can I group this to SUM ISS.InvoiceTotal grouped by CustomerKey?

I keep getting the "is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." error.

Any ideas?

Comment: CustomerKey is presumably the primary key of vwAC_SSR_Customer. Is PartsSalesOrderInvoiceID the primary key of vwSV_INV_PartsSalesOrder or vwAC_SSR_InvoiceSalesSummary? Your outer joins don't work by the way, because you dismiss all outer-joined records in your where clause.

Comment: Are the following assumptions correct? 1. The query can find more then one `ISS` record for one `CU` record. 2. The query can find more then one `PSO` record for one `ISS` record. 3. The query can find more then one `CF` record for one `CU` record.

Comment: 1. yes
2. no it is a 1 to 1 relationship
3. yes, it can find more than one CF record per CU record.  However, the CF table is one I can do without if it makes it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `SUM()` in the ISS table you can't select from it or add it to the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
    [CustomerKey] AS 'Cust #',
    CU.[CompanyName] AS 'Company Name',
    LAST(ISS.InvoiceDate) AS 'Invoice Date',
    SUM(ISS.InvoiceTotal) AS 'Invoice Total',
    ISNULL(CU.ShopPhone,'') AS 'Company Shop',
    ISNULL(CU.CellPhone,'') AS 'Company Cell',
    ISNULL(CU.OfficePhone,'') AS 'Company Office',
    ISNULL(CF.FirstName, '') AS 'FName',
    ISNULL(CF.LastName,'') AS 'LName',
    ISNULL(CF.WorkPhone,'') AS 'Contact Work',
    ISNULL(CF.CellPhone,'') AS 'Contact Cell',
    ISNULL(CF.HomePhone,'') AS 'Contact Home',
    ISNULL(CF.EMail,'') AS 'Contact Email',
    PSO.OutsidePartsSalespersonName
FROM 
    [ProfitMaster].[dbo].[vwAC_SSR_Customer] CU with (nolock)
LEFT JOIN 
    [ProfitMaster].[dbo].[vwAC_SSR_InvoiceSalesSummary] ISS with (nolock) ON CU.CustomerKey = ISS.Customer
JOIN 
    [ProfitMaster].[dbo].[vwSV_INV_PartsSalesOrder] PSO with (nolock) ON PSO.PartsSalesOrderInvoiceID = ISS.PartsSalesOrderInvoiceID
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         EntityID, FirstName, LastName, WorkPhone, CellPhone, HomePhone, EMail 
     FROM 
         [ProfitMaster].[dbo].[vwGB_CON_ContactFull] with (nolock)  
     WHERE 
         EntityID IS NOT NULL 
         AND FirstName <> '' 
         AND EntityTypeID = '3' 
         AND SetDefault = '1'
     GROUP BY 
         EntityID, FirstName, LastName, WorkPhone, CellPhone, HomePhone, EMail) AS CF ON CU.CustomerID = CF.EntityID
WHERE 
    CU.Inactive = '0' 
    AND ISS.InvoiceType = 'Parts Order'
    AND ISS.InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2017-03-31 3:59:59.000'
    AND CU.CustomerBaseBranchID = '1'
    AND PSO.OutsidePartsSalespersonName IN ('Dave Freeland', 'Mark Miller', 'Ryan Oaks')
GROUP BY 
    CU.CustomerKey, CU.[CompanyName],
    CU.ShopPhone, CU.CellPhone, CU.OfficePhone, 
    CF.FirstName, CF.LastName, CF.WorkPhone, CF.CellPhone, 
    CF.HomePhone, CF.EMail, PSO.OutsidePartsSalespersonName
ORDER BY 
    CU.CompanyName
```